# lwuit logs nothing

Tags: logging, java-me, lwuit

I'm trying to log an exception using lwuit Log class.:

```
catch(Exception ex){
     Log.setLevel(Log.DEBUG);
     Log.e(ex);
     Log.p("test error");
     Log.showLog();
}
```

But it shows just an empty `Form`. Even the "test error" is not there.

I checked `Log.getLogContent() and Log.getFileURL()`. Both are null.

What's the problem?

Versions I use are: LWUIT 1.5,  NetBeans 6.9.1 (-> WTK 2.5.2) and JDK 1.6

Comment: Refer this [LWUIT Forum link](http://www.java.net/forum/topic/mobile-embedded/lwuit/lwuit-logs-nothing) for the solution